# Draw an UIImage with Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics

I want to **draw on screen** an image retrieved from PhotoLibrary using **CGContextRef** or **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** .

I tried the following code but it doesn't draw anything on screen. I'm currently using cocos2d and box2d. What's wrong?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Dismiss UIImagePickerController and release it
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[picker.view removeFromSuperview];
[picker release];

// Let's create a sprite now that we have an image

//CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
//[self addChild:imageFromPicker];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[newImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 70, 370 );
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
//CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40), newImage.CGImage);
//CGImageRelease(newImage);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't tell Cocoa (touch or otherwise) to suddenly start drawing. It asks your app how it should draw certain views, and you tell it in the `drawRect` method of your view subclasses. At this point a graphics context is already created.

Your code is creating a graphics context and drawing to it, but this drawing is not done on screen.

To draw a specific image at a specific position, you would typically assign the image object to some view (like your sprite in the code above? I'm not familiar with cocos2d) which already knows how to draw an image. Then you'd put that view on the screen (your commented out addChild call?). You could add the necessary transform to the view object and this would be taken into account.

Briefly looking at the cocos2d documents, CCSprite inherits from CCNode, which can have a transform applied to it- you can set rotation and scale parameters. I suggest you look into that.

Comment: And since the questioner will probably wonder: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is used to create an image, not to draw to the screen. You already have an image, so just hand it to a view (specifically, one that is in the view hierarchy) that knows how to draw it.

Comment: i agree to it all..but its not a view based class its a cclayer based class(so drawrect method is not an option i guess).. i need to perform actions(like scaling the image) so i wanted to get the image in some graphiccontext object so i could manipulate it in the draw method??

Comment: You can apply a transform to a CCSprite. I have edited my answer.